# GeoGebra graph for $x^{(\mathrm{integer}_1, \mathrm{integer}_2)}$

Tags: graphing-functions, exponentiation

Whenever I ask GeoGebra to draw a graph of $x^{(\mathrm{integer}_1, \mathrm{integer}_2)}$
it outputs a strange structure for which I have no more rigorous description than a "bar-like spiral".
The following picture will, hopefully, provide better insight.
[image: GeoGebra graph of x^(10, 3)]

I am not aware that something else than a scalar can be used as an exponent. If yes, what is it? Interval? Vector? Or is the whole thing just some GeoGebra's quirk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the notation
$$
f(x) = x^{m,n}
$$
(with optional parentheses around $m,n$)
is interpreted as the complex function
$$
f(x) = x^{m + ni}.
$$
Then, the image of the square grid from $-10 - 10i$ to $10 + 10i$ is plotted as a 2D graph.

Here are a few examples.

$$
f(x) = x^{1,0}
$$

[image]

$$
f(x) = x^{2,0}
$$

[image]

$$
f(x) = x^{1,1}
$$

[image]

$$
f(x) = x^{-3,0}
$$

[image]